# XCOM 2 "Frost Bomb" immunities / vulnerabilities

Tags: xcom-2

I failed to find some useful information about what enemies are immune or may be especially vulnerable to the `Frost Bomb` (Alien Hunters DLC weapon).

The Sectopod for example seems to be somewhat immune, but I think it loses one of its actions in the following turn.

I also think that the Elite Muton from Long War is completely immune, but I am not 100% sure. Maybe I just barely missed it?

So, what "Frost Bomb" immunities/vulnerabilities are there?

Answer (score 3):

The Sectopod and Gatekeeper are both highly resistant to the Frost Bomb, but it's not entirely clear *how* it works.
Here's how I think it works:

- They still take the -10 defense penalty, for the duration of the turn you freeze them on.
- They lose all their moves on the following turn (they don't just lose "one action point"), although I've seen a Gatekeeper thawing and shooting a civilian on the same turn. This could possibly just be a developer oversight.
- Freezing a Gatekeeper [will still](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/4krcqh/psa_xcom2_frost_bombs_and_gatekeepers/) kill all of its Psi Zombies.

I haven't seen anything especially vulnerable to it, though Chryssalids do tend to pile up once activated, making it easy to freeze an entire pod. The Alien Rulers are susceptible, but not any more susceptible to Freeze effects than they are to, say, being stunned.

I have no idea how well LW2 muton elites fare against it, but you could probably get answers under [xcom-2-long-war-2](/questions/tagged/xcom-2-long-war-2).